Are $SO(3)\times_{U(1)} \mathbb{R}^2$ and $SU(2)\times_{U(1)} \mathbb{R}^2$ diffeomorphic?
$U(1)/\mathbb{Z}_4=S^1$, this $U(1)$ action extends to a cohomogeneity one action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which preserves and acts transitively on circles centered at the origin. By identifying $U(1)$ with the following group
$$\bigg\lbrace\pmatrix{e^{i\theta}&0\\ 0&e^{-i\theta}}:\theta\in[0,2\pi)\bigg\rbrace,$$
we can see $U(1)$ as a subgroup of $SU(2)$. Then we can define the twisted product space $SU(2)\times_{U(1)} \mathbb{R}^2$ as the orbit space of the action
$$(g_1,(g_2,x))\mapsto(g_2g_1^{-1},g_1x),
\forall g_1\in U(1),g_2\in SU(2),x\in\mathbb{R}^2.$$
Similarly, we can define another twisted product space $SO(3)\times_{U(1)}\mathbb{R}^2$. Here $U(1)/\mathbb{Z}_2=S^1$ and extends to a cohomogeneity one action on $\mathbb{R}^2.$ And we identify $U(1)$ with the following group
$$\bigg\lbrace\pmatrix{cos(\theta)& -sin(\theta)&0\\ sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1}:\theta\in[0,2\pi)\bigg\rbrace$$
in this case.
Since we have a universal covering map $Spin: SU(2)\to SO(3)$ with kernel $\mathbb{Z}_2,$  it is easy to show that $SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_4$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(3)/\mathbb{Z}_2.$ But I have no idea how to construct a diffeomorphism from these two twisted product and I feel that they actually can not be diffeomorphic(even there is no homeomorphism between them).
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

You're right that those two spaces are not even homeomorphic, and the reason for that is that they their fundamental groups are not even isomorphic.
What you need to prove this is a theorem of algebraic topology regarding fiber bundles: given a fiber bundle $F \to E \to B$ (with nice enough fiber $F$ and base $B$) there is a long exact sequence of homotopy groups, of which I record the following portion:
$$\pi_2(B) \to \pi_1(F) \to \pi_1(E) \to \pi_1(B)
$$
In your case, both fiber bundles have base $B=\mathbb R^2$ which is contractible, so its homotopy groups $\pi_2(B)$ and $\pi_1(B)$ are trivial, and hence you have an isomorphism $\pi_1(E)\approx \pi_1(F)$ in both fiber bundles. Also, in each of your two twisted product spaces (the "$E$" term) the fiber of the fiber bundle (the "$F$" term) is the Lie group factor. So

$\pi_1\bigl(SU(2)\times_{U(1)} \mathbb{R}^2\bigr) \approx \pi_1(SU(2))$ which is trivial
$\pi_1\bigl(SO(3)\times_{U(1)} \mathbb{R}^2\bigr) \approx \pi_1(SO(3))$ which is cyclic of order $2$.


Why do these two twisted spaces have a fiber bundle structure with fiber a Lie group and a $\mathbb{R}^2$ base? I only know $SU(2)\times_{U(1)}\mathbb{R}^2$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $\mathbb{R}^2$ and base $SU(2)/U(1)=S^2$ from theorem 3.57 of the book "Lie groups and geometric aspects of isometric actions".  If there are some good references?

In general, when you have one Lie group $Q$ acting on another one $K$ with twisted Lie group $\Gamma = K \rtimes Q$, then you have a submersion homomorphism $q : \Gamma \mapsto Q$ with kernel $K$. Furthermore, $Q$ is covered by coordinate neighborhoods $U \subset Q$ such that $q^{-1}(U)$ is diffeomorphic to $K \times U$, and such that the diffeomorphism commutes with the two projections to $U$, namely $q^{-1}(U) \to U$ and $K \times U \to U$. This verifies the definition of a fiber bundle with fiber $K$ and base $Q$.

One can compare this to abstract group theory, with no manifold structures present, where the construction $\Gamma = K \rtimes Q$ is known as a semidirect product. Again, in that abstract setting, there is a quotient map $\Gamma \mapsto Q$ with kernel $K$. In fact, even in the Lie group setting one gets a semidirect product; the extra information used to derive the fiber bundle structure comes from the manifold structures on $K \times U$ and on $q^{-1}(U) \subset \Gamma$.

I don't have a good textbook recommendation for the twisted product construction, but I can recommend almost any good abstract algebra book for the semidirect product construction on which the twisted product construction is based. One such good book is Herstein's Abstract Algebra.
